# IE8 PNG Alpha Transparency without filter AlphaImageLoader?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8

So I'm attempting to optimize a product image carousel which cycles through items as if rotating in 3d. Hard to describe, so better to show here: http://www.costadelmar.com/shop/sunglasses

There remains one last slowdown in IE8 -- applying the filter: AlphaImageLoader styling. It's the final difference between "blazingly fast" and "why did you even bother."

Are there any ways to achieve PNG alpha channel transparency without using that filter?

Comment: Pretty sure IE>=7 natively supports the 24bit PNG alpha channel...

Comment: Looks like my assets are 32bit. I'll see what converting to 24 does for me and come back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 disabled the use of CSS filters. It has perfect support for 24bit png's though.

Comment: My assets were fine-- turns out, somebody had applied a gradient filter through CSS which was stopping the transparency from working. Anybody with a similar problem, be sure that you're not applying any unusual styles to your image.